React-Native Firebase Messaging - Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found
I'm attempting to setup android push notifications within expo for my react native app and running into trouble. I have notifications successfully working for ios but when I run my build on my android phone I get the following error in the adb logs as well as in my react native side
W FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. 
This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful

I'm also getting this error returned from my react native code
ERROR  Error getting Expo push token: [Error: Call to function 'ExpoPushTokenManager.getDevicePushTokenAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.reet. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.]

React Native code
async function registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
    console.log('registerForPushNotificationsAsync called');
    let token;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        console.log('Setting up Android notification channel');
        Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
        });
    }

    if (Device.isDevice) {
        console.log('Device is a physical device'); // Debugging log
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
        console.log(`Existing notification permission status: ${existingStatus}`);
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
            console.log(`Requested notification permission status: ${status}`);
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            console.log('Push notification permissions not granted');
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }
        console.log(`Final Status:  ${finalStatus}`)
        try {
            console.log(`Project ID: ${Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId}`)
            token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
                projectId: Constants.expoConfig.extra.eas.projectId,
            });
            console.log(`Expo push token: ${token.data}`); // Debugging log
            return token.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting Expo push token:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Running on an emulator, push notifications won’t work');
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications - will not work on emulators');
        return;
    }
}

Root-Level build.gradle (Project-Level):
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.8' apply false
    id 'com.facebook.react' version '0.73.6' apply false
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

App-Level build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.facebook.react'
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    namespace "com.reet"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reet"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1.2"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false
            include(*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride = defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    implementation('org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.46.1.0')

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

    hermesEnabled = (findProperty('expo.jsEngine') ?: "hermes") == "hermes"

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle")
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



I've been doing circles on this for a few days now and would greatly appreciate any help!
Things ive tried so far

Changing com.google.gms.google-services version (most popular fix)
Changing bom version (was originally 32.0.0)
adding FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) to MainApplication.kt (doesnt work if I have it or not)
verifiying my google-services.json file was correct and in correct place

